# How to extract a submatrix of a SparseMat

Tags: opencv

I have a SparseMat A with 50x50 dimensions.
I have another matrix B with 10x10 dimensions.
I want to add a submatrix of A (0~10 x 0~10) with B.
How to extract submatrix of a SparseMat.
I did like in Mat as A(Range(0,10), Range(0,10)), the error is  "call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type". How to solve that problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These functions are not implemented in OpenCV (very few operations are actually implemented on sparse matrices).

What you need to do is to loop over the sparse matrix using the provided `SparseMatConstIterator_<T>` iterator, test if the position of the non-zero point is in your subregion of interest, then write it.
You have to loop over the non-zero elements of your input sparse matrix, but you can maybe add a test for early exit when the target matrix is full.

By the way, 50x50 is not so big. You can maybe switch to dense matrices for easier matrix handling. I work with 1024x1024 matrices in OpenCV on a regular basis.